# XMPP over TCP Titanium

Tags: android, ios, tcp, titanium, xmpp

I am trying to figure out a smart way to use XMPP over TCP in Titanium without much hassle such as creating a module for an existing library in iOS/Android. I have also considered modifying a Strophe.js library I found online using XMPP over TCP to use the Titanium TCP module which would be enough to make it work on Titanium as far as I can tell, but that would take disproportionately long time to the project's completion time that I am working on. Does anyone have any suggestions on a faster solution?

Comment: found a solution for this?

Comment: Well yeah i took upon updating this [repository](https://github.com/jmartin82/titanium-xmpp) and making it ios and android compatible and it is working fine, not perfectly, just fine, but it did the trick, I will be open sourcing my refinements after I have cleared up some code

Comment: I will thank you A LOT!!! What service are you using? I am trying to integrate quickblox.